# How to add Internal Web Browser like Safari or Chrome in Eclipse plugin View

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I want to integrate External Browser like Safari or Chrome in Eclipse plugin View.I was trying to do it with Registry but its launching externally when click on View.I want to open it internally inside Eclipse  View.What is the way to do it? Is there any webclient for these Browsers?

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is to create a editor for your plugin and add the Browser widget  in the plugin

```
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, Boolean.getBoolean("do.not.use.mozilla.browser") ?SWT.NONE : SWT.MOZILLA
```

Comment: Thanks but i want to add Safari browser as Internal browser but there is no API for Safari.